# How to run js code pulled from server side in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Laravel as my back-end and Angularjs as my front-end for my website. I need to pull some js code (advertisement purposes, like Adsense) from server side and run it in Angularjs.

I got some ideas from https://www.ng-book.com/p/Security/ . First I use $sce to make the js code trusted so that angularjs can run it,

```
$scope.safeJsCode = $sce.trustAsJs($scope.unsafeJsCode);
```

then I use [ng-load](https://github.com/andrefarzat/ng-load) to eval() the safeJsCode

```
<script ng-load="run()"> </script>
$scode.run() = function()
{
    eval($scope.safeJsCode.toString());
};
```

However, I was not able to run it. Can someone give me some ideas on how to solve this predicament? Thanks!

Comment: Try using $scope.$eval($scope.safeJsCode.toString()). This might help.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you think that ng-load can call your 'run' function.

Empty script tag won't fire a 'load' event, so no wonder that it is not being executed.

If you really need to dynamically load some script and execute it you don't need no script tags-just as soon as you fetch script from the server and get safeJsCode, eval it.

Now I don't expect you to heed my advice, but instead of doing eval(), you should really think about a way how you can achieve with just data. In most cases this can be solved by just having your own smart code.
There are case which comes to mind- like a dashboard with customizable widgets, where people can write 3rd party widgets. Problem is, these never catch on and they are very prone to bugs and usually are sluggish.
If you trully need dynamicity though, you could try loading those script with https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs